# Hide divi module with advanced custom fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, visibility, divi

I hope anyone can help me.

Is there a way to toggle the visibility of a Divi module with ACF in Wordpress?

I tried it myself an searched in forums

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use ACF Plugin for that.

Steps for that:

1. Install the ACF plugin.
2. create the new custom field group in ACF and add the toggle field in that.
3. Assign this group to relevant post types and taxonomy.
4. Edit the Divi module that you watch to show/hide based on the ACF field.
5. Go to the advanced tab in the module setting and add the CSS class **"acf-toggle-module"**.
6. Add the below code to your theme function file(**Function.php**).

```html
add_filter( 'body_class', 'acf_toggle_module_class' );
function acf_toggle_module_class( $classes ) {
    if( get_field('acf_toggle_module') ) {
        $classes[] = 'hide-module';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

7. Add the CSS to style sheet(**Style.css**).

```css
.hide-module .acf-toggle-module {
    display: none !important;
}
```